# Using touchesBegan in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having some troubles with the function `touchesBegan`. Problem is that when `touchesBegan` executes, image person jumps on the position defined at the beginning in Main.storyboard. Here is my code:

```
    var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)


    @IBOutlet weak var person: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var value: UILabel!




    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch

        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        person.center = location

        value.text = "X: \(person.center.x), Y: \(person.center.y)"
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch

        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        person.center = location
```

Problem starts when I add line:

```
value.text = "X: \(person.center.x), Y: \(person.center.y)"
```

Any idea why? I printed location and person.center, they both point to the position where I click. But image person goes to the position defined on beginning of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the image view to redraw itself with:

```
person.setNeedsDisplay()
```

or you can set the content mode to redraw itself whenever the image view bounds are changed:

```
person.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw // Only once
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of issue, where a UI control moves back to its original position when you update a label is generally a result of auto layout (namely, updating a label triggers the auto layout constraints to be reapplied, moving an object back to its original location). If you don't update the label, the constraints will not be reapplied, and you won't have the problem of the moved object moving back to its original position.

But that notwithstanding, with auto layout you generally shouldn't be updating `frame` and/or `center` values at all, but rather update the `constant` property of the constraints that dictate where the object is located. So, add `IBOutlet` references for the constraints, and then update the `constant`.

But, bottom line, there are all sorts of things that can trigger auto layout to reapply its constraints, so you really want to fix the constraints rather than manually moving the object around.